# HTML files not displaying correctly iOS

Tags: ios, email, html

I am trying to email an html file with some charts in it and it doesn't show any of the content if I open in the Mail app on iOS except a bulleted point, whereas it is fine in a browser or any other email client. I tried downloading it but it still doesn't give the option to open it in Safari or any compatible app, where I think it would display properly.

Comment: Does the file have links to the charts or is it all embedded

Comment: It is all embedded